# Sending commands with Paramiko to BOSCLI shell

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

I need to parse the output of a command on a remote machine I have to connect via SSH.

This remote machine runs Ubuntu and I can only access the SSH via a "console wrapper" (sorry don't know the exact term for it) called BOSCLI in which I can only run a set of specific commands.
On connect I get a prompt for sudo password, after entered I'm at the prompt and I do not need to enter it again.

At first I started using `exec_command` which didn't work, for obvious reasons. I have switched now to `invoke_shell()` and then using `send()` but only the password prompt is sent, and not the following command.
Of course I've read a lot of other questions here and other websites with no success...

```
def conectar(url,user,passw, puerto, sudoPass):
    cliente = paramiko.SSHClient()
    cliente.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    cliente.connect(url,port=puerto, username=user, password=passw)
    if cliente.get_transport() is None: raise Exception(paramiko.SSHException)
    time.sleep(2)
    canal = cliente.invoke_shell()  
    stdin = canal.makefile('wb')
    stdout = canal.makefile('rb')
    stderr = canal.makefile_stderr('r')
    while not canal.recv_ready():
        time.sleep(2)
    aux = canal.send(sudoPass+'\n') #sudo pass 
    out = canal.recv(1024)
    print(aux)
    time.sleep(1)
    aux = canal.send('''dhcp pool status\n''')
    print(aux)

    out += canal.recv(9999)
    #ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = cliente.exec_command('dhcp pool status',get_pty=True)
    #ssh_stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
    cliente.close()
    print(stdout.read())
    print(stderr.read())
    print(out.decode('ascii'))
```

The output should be a long text with all the DHCP statistics on the different pools for the next method to parse, however I'm receiving empty outputs.

There's a thing also that is confusing me the most right now which is that actually 'out' has content (which is the welcome MOTD, etc on the shell), but `stdout` is empty.

```
print(aux) returns 9 first  
print(aux) returns 17 afterwards.  
print(stdout.read()) returns b''  
print(stderr.read()) returns b''
```

`out` content is the following:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-66-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Tue Jul  2 11:34:22 CEST 2019

  System load:  0.42               Users logged in:        0
  Usage of /:   32.9% of 26.51GB   IP address for eth0:    
  Memory usage: 22%                IP address for eth1:    
  Swap usage:   4%                 IP address for eth2:    
  Processes:    194                IP address for docker0:

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

Last login: Tue Jul  
[sudo] password for bos:

(pho-xem1)  (Nuevo)  bcli 0 [] normal>
```

Which is the command prompt after passing the sudo pass.

Comment: What do you get in `out`?

Comment: `b'\r\n\r\n(pho-xem1)  (Nuevo)  bcli 0 [] normal> '` which is the command prompt.

Comment: And the first `canal.recv(1024)`?

Comment: I've added to the question the output of `print(out.decode('ascii'))`

Comment: Did you try waiting after `aux = canal.send('''dhcp pool status\n''')`?

Comment: Oh my... can't believe it but adding `while canal.recv_ready():
            time.sleep(1)
            out += canal.recv(1024)` works. However I still have `stdout` empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably send the command too early, before the server (or actually the boscli shell) expects it.

You should wait for the prompt, before you send the command.

Or as a quick and dirty hack, just wait for a short interval.

---

As for the `stdout`: `stdout` is just a wrapper around `Channel.recv`. As you are already consuming the output in `Channel.recv`, you won't get anything more in `stdout`. Either read `stdout` or use `Channel.recv`, but not both.